# How to test nodejs modules that transitively require itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

Assume the following scenario :

Rest client is a module, which has many middlewares; which are themselves modules.

Now, we're trying to create a new middleware that requires client itself to fetch/update metadata for the client input url.

Testing this middleware, will bring in a published version of the client from npm registry, because middleware has a devDependency on the client. But we want to serve our local client.

Also, the published version of client does not contain this new middleware, so it will not allow testing the request pipeline with this middleware.

We want to initiate the client with this middleware, when we're testing the middleware itself to send a request to fetch data.

The middleware is smart enough to not request metadata for metadata, so it will skip the second call. The new flow should be like the diagram below :

[image: New request flow should be like this]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the nodejs module loader, to return local client instead of published one when client is requested during test execution.

```
describe(()=>{
  const localClient = require('../client');
  const m = require('module');
  const orig = m._load;

  before(()=>{
    m._load = function(name){
      if(name==='client'){
        return localClient;
      }
      return orig.appy(this, arguments)
    }
  });

  after(()=>{
    m._load = orig;
  });

  it('test goes here',()=>{...})
})
```